# CoreData many-to-many relationship

Tags: core-data, many-to-many

How to operate with many-to-many relationship in CoreData? 
For example:

I have 2 entities - Recipes & Ingredients

CoreData links them like Recipes <<-->> Ingredients.
Now I need to add attribute "Count" for every Ingredient in Recipe. How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: What did you mean 'I need to add attribute "Count" for every Ingredient'? Does it means that you want to add new NSAttributeDescription or just update this property with new value?

Comment: @MarkKryzhanouski

Recipes has 3 columns: name, thumbImage, ingredients
Ingredients has 2 column: name, recipe
Recipe.ingredients <<-->> Ingredients.recipe

Now I need to add column "Count" (count of some ingredient in some recipe)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Core Data takes care of the object graph consistency maintenance for you. So if you use a SQLite store, Core Data automatically creates the intermediate join table for you for many-to-many relationships. In your case, you should explicitly create an intermediate (“join”) entity. An advantage of the intermediate entity is that you can also use it to add more information to the
relationship—for example a “IngredientInfo” entity might include 'Count' column. So you model should look like: **Recipe <-->> IngredientInfo <<--> Ingredient**.

If you find something unclear here I'll update the answer.

**Update: Access ingredients and count**

```
    for (IngredientInfo* ingredientInfo in recipe.ingredientInfos) {
        Ingredient* ingredient = ingredientInfo.ingredient;
        NSNumber* count = ingredientInfo.count;
    }
```

Or to quick access to all ingredients in certain Recipe use KVC

```
NSSet* ingredients = [recipe valueForKeyPath:@"ingredientInfo.ingredient"];
```

Comment: I think it should be `IngredientInfo <<--> Ingredient`, otherwise you could use an ingredient only for a single recipe.

Comment: @Mark
Thank you! It is what I need

Comment: @Mark
How should I get the set of Ingredients and their count when I select some Recipe?

Comment: @MarkKryzhanouski if i not create IngredientInfo then is it any way to update entities from both sides?

Comment: @msmq If you don't create intermediate join table by your self then just set up many-to-many relationships between Recipe <<-->> Ingredient entities with corresponding names ingredients/recipes in CoreData model builder and access through relationship property in both sides. Example recipe.ingredients or ingredient.recipes. Hope its clear.

Comment: Great answer. Any way I can translate this into Swift/SwiftUI?