# Fetching data using join-table in CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, fetch

I have three tables with relations like on the picture below. 
With the help of **Mark Kryzhanouski** ([CoreData many-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973660/coredata-many-to-many-relationship/14975539#comment21036447_14975539)) I know how to access to the set of all ingredients in some recipe:

```
NSMutableArray* ingredients = [recipe valueForKeyPath:@"ingredients.ingredient"];
```

But I would like to access to the list of ingredients by fetching. Because in the future I will prepare "to cart" function.

[image: Scheme]

I did this in that way

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY count.inRecipe == %@", self.recipe];
```

is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, it is correct.

To display the `count` and `inCart` properties of an ingredient for a recipe, you have to find the *Join* object that is related to the recipe and to the ingredient.

The following predicate for the *Join* entity should give that result:

```
NSManagedObject *theIngredient;
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"inRecipe == %@ AND ingredient == %@", self.recipe, theIngredient]
```

Comment: thank you @Martin, but than how can I access to "count" and "inCart" fields?

Comment: @Romowski: Sorry, but I do not understand your question. Did you check if the predicate works and gives the intended results?

Comment: yes, predicate works correctly... Result of this fetch displays in UITableView, in cell I need to show **Ingredients.name** and **Join.count**, **Join.inCart**

Comment: @Romowski: OK, now I understood. See my updated answer, I hope that it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can I use this in my **cellForRowAtIndexPath**?
May be there is some way to use **valueForKeyPath** or **valueForKey**?

Comment: @Romowski: The ingredient is related to many Count objects, but you want only the one count object that belongs to the recipe. Therefore a simple valueForKey... Does not work.

Comment: It would be nice to know if anything is wrong in the answer, so that I can try to fix it.