# CoreData: Add same object multiple times in the To-Many Relationship

Tags: ios, core-data

Is there any way of adding the same object multiple times i the default CoreData one-to-many relationship?

I have one table with **recipes** in it, and one table with **ingredients**.

This is what I'm aiming at:

```
Apple cake
  - Apple
  - Apple
  - Apple
  - Sugar
  - Flour

Other cake
  - Apple
  - Sugar
  - Flour
  - Flour
```

By default, the `addIngredientsObject`-method only adds the ingredient if it doesn't exist in the recipe.

Do I have to create my own table with something like:

```
Recipe ID
Ingredient ID
Count
```

or is it possible with the To-Many relationship?

Comment: If your objects are actually recipes you most likely need an intermediate Entity which has an amount attribute and a relationship to ingredient anyway. It's probably not a good idea to add 500 relationships to flour if you need 500g flour ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [CoreData many-to-many relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973660/coredata-many-to-many-relationship)

Comment: @MatthiasBauch indeed, and how would you add half an Apple? :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I did the intermediate Entity with two relationships and a count field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd listen to Matthias with this.

Create a relationship like...

```
Recipe <->> IngredientMeasure <<-> Ingredient.
```

i.e. Recipe can have many ingredient measures. Ingredient measure only has one ingredient.

To answer your question though.

In a "to-many" relationship the relationship is mapped to an `NSSet`. `NSSet` is a unique collection of objects.

So, if you create an entity called `apple` and do something like...

```
[myRecipe addIngredientObject:apple];
[myRecipe addIngredientObject:apple];
[myRecipe addIngredientObject:apple];
[myRecipe addIngredientObject:apple];
```

You will still end up with only one apple as it is adding the same item to an NSSet which will stop the duplicates.